# Ionic (Ng-Cordova) With Onesignal

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, onesignal

I'm using Ng-Cordova and onesignal.
I was used cordova with onesignal successful. But ng-cordova not working successful.
My onesignal register code is in index.html
I try app.run  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() 
but is not working . My question is How get onesignal id after the register. And where write is my true code?

My index.html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  // Enable to debug issues.
  // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

  var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
   // alert('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  };
alert("deviceready");
  window.plugins.OneSignal.init("******************",
                                 {googleProjectNumber: "***********",autoRegister: true},
                                 notificationOpenedCallback);

   window.plugins.OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
    window.plugins.OneSignal.enableNofiticationWhenActive(true);
  window.plugins.OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications();
  // Show an alert box if a notification comes in when the user is in your app.
  window.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);

    window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
         $("#ids").val(ids.userId);
         alert(ids.userId);
      });

}, false);
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> For Ionic 1:

In your `app.js`

```
window.plugins.OneSignal
        .startInit("Your-Onesignal App Id")
        .endInit();
```

In your `controller` use:

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.getIds(function(ids) {
                  $scope.noti_user_id    = ids.userId;  
                  $scope.noti_user_token = ids.pushToken;
            });
```

Make Sure to use same App id as having in `config.xml` while register new app at onesignal Dashboard.